# How to traverse on List<Type> which contains List of the same Type

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a `List` of `Type` class which has the following structure:

```
class Type {
    private String name;
    private String level;
    private List<Type> types;
}
```

Here is my `AnotherType` which in a result I would like to build.

```
class AnotherType {
    private String name; 
    private List<AnotherType> types;
}
```

I'm building `List<Type>` object from request which is coming from `UI`:

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "level": "1",
      "name": "Name1"
    },
    {
      "level": "2",
      "name": "Name2",
      "types": [
        {
          "level": "2.1",
          "title": "Name2.1",
          "types": [
            {
              "level": "2.1.1",
              "name": "Name2.1.1"
            },
            {
              "level": "2.1.2",
              "title": "Name2.1.2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level": "3",
      "name": "Name3",
      "types": [
        {
          "level": "3.1",
          "name": "Name3.1",
          "types": [
            {
              "level": "3.1.1",
              "name": "Name3.1.1"
            },
            {
              "level": "3.1.2",
              "name": "Name3.1.2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that the each `types` can be there or can be `null`.

I don`t know how deep can it go.

My question is how can I recursively (or maybe iterative ) traverse to this `List<Type>` and construct `List<AnotherType>`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to do? Provide your piece of code, and maybe we gonna help you to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I tried to build it using `Order Traversals` and tried to build it using `Level Order Traversal`, but  seems this is completely different structure

Comment: Please provide piece of code, nobody will do full task for you. People don't do any kind of "homework" here.

Comment: It's not an "homework", I'm sure this is a common thing. I'm not asking so someone will do it for me. Someone has definitely seen this issue before.  I'm out of keywords to search similar issues in Google

Comment: I don't really get it... Could you add a sample of what you expect `AnotherType` to hold? Are they actually the same and only difference is the `level`? So it ends up being a copy without the level?

Comment: @Roland both `Type` and `AnotherType` are pretty complex. But the basic structure for `Type` is what it is now. My goal is to read the `List<Type>` and make similar (complex) `AnotherType` object.

Comment: So I would go for a model mapping or transformation tool then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add getters/setters in your classes to access and modify your private fields. Then you can use the following method which recursively converts `Type` to `AnotherType`.

```
public AnotherType toAnotherType(Type type) {

    AnotherType anotherType = new AnotherType();
    anotherType.setName(type.getName());

    if (type.getTypes() != null && !type.getTypes().isEmpty()) {

        List<AnotherType> lAnotherTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Type innerType : type.getTypes()) {
            AnotherType innerAnotherType = toAnotherType(innerType);
            lAnotherTypes.add(innerAnotherType);
        }
        anotherType.setTypes(lAnotherTypes);
    }   

    return anotherType;
}
```

Then having this method you can traverse once on `List<Type>` and call `toAnotherType` method for every `Type`:

```
List<AnotherType> allAnotherTypes = new ArrayList<>();

for (Type type : types) {
    AnotherType anotherType = toAnotherType(type);
    allAnotherTypes.add(anotherType);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. .Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are searching something like a model mapper, e. g. [modelmapper.org](http://modelmapper.org/)

Otherwise traversing through your object can be done in several ways. One possibility:

```
AnotherType transform(Type type) {
  if (type == null) {
    return null;
  }
  AnotherType anotherType = new AnotherType();
  anotherType.name = type.name;
  if (type.types != null) {
    anotherType.types = type.types.stream()
        .map(this::transform)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  return anotherType;
}
```

Afterwards call that function like:

```
Type toTransform ...
AnotherType anotherType = transform(toTransform);
```

(of course: add modifiers and visibility depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a function on your class that runs the same function on all classes in the list and then return the answer pluss it self.

Something like this

```
class Myclass
{
    list<Myclass> items = new List<Myclass>();

    List<Myclass> GetItems()
    {
     var result = items.SelectMany(a => a.GetItems()).Tolist();
     result.add(this);
     return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive pseudocode (without bracket formatting):

```
function WalkList(List<Type> aList, int aLevel = 0)
   if (aList) //not null
       output aList.name, level after aLevel  spaces
       WalkList(aList.types, aLevel + 1)
```

Comment: I didn't get this part :  level after aLevel spaces

Comment: This is the simplest tree output formatting: when you form output string with name, insert some spaces in the string beginning to make different indents for different levels (it is better to insert 4*aLevel spaces)

Comment: P.S. It is not needed for data reatment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your classes look like this, nobody would be able to access them - all members are private, there are no getters/setters or public constructors that will initialize private members. Once you fix this, the code for conversion is the following:

```
List<AnotherType> convert(List<Type> tList) {
    if(tList == null)
        return null;
    List<AnotherType> retVal = new ArrayList<AnotherType>();
    for(Type t : tList) {
        List<AnotherType> aTypes = convert(t.types);
        retVal.add(new AnotherType(t.name, aTypes));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```